# Python scripting in Power BI - how to add parameters to edit Python script

Tags: python, powerbi

I am running a Python script in Power BI which does some calculations on a data source and creates a table 'PythonTable'. This table is then used by a report. Somewhere in the script, this can be found:

```
overall=pd.concat([name,lang,cert],axis=1)
subs = (df_function(overall, overall.T)).stack()
```

The code is using the variable 'overall' which combines some variables like name, lang cert. I would like to add a slicer in Power BI which can select for example name and lang, so the script will change to:

```
overall=pd.concat([name,lang],axis=1)
```

And hence 'PythonTable' will be updated. I could also just choose name, so the script will be:

```
overall=pd.concat([name],axis=1)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: pretty easy to set up some booleans based on some kind of input and then run it through if statements. Even better would be to make that argument to `pd.concat()` a list comprehension where only desired values are allowed through. If that is confusing I can elaborate.

Comment: @Bill I am not sure how to add a list of possible values to pass to pd.concat(), could you please elaborate on the steps?